# included php files causing error

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I have a script that I am trying to include php files to from my affiliate tracking script. both scripts are on the same vps and I know that the affiliate tracking script can work because I have successfully included it to a different script in the same way.

In this case the inclusion of the tracking code causes the page to not complete loading.

I have tried turning on php errors from cpanel and at the top of the php file, but am not seeing any error reporting

kind of stumped. can anyone see what the error is, or what I may have done wrong?

Thanks everyone.

included lines:

```
$sale_amount = '10.00';
$product = 'Drive-Plan';
include('partners/controller/record-sale.php);
```

Complete php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use Auth;
use Input;
use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Plan;

class PaymentsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('loggedIn');
        $this->middleware('paymentsEnabled');

        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->settings = App::make('App\Services\Settings');

        Stripe::setApiKey($this->settings->get('stripe_secret_key'));
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe user to a plan or swap him to a different plan.
     *
     * @return response
     */
    public function upgrade() {
        if ($this->user->subscribed()) {
            $this->user->subscription(Input::get('plan'))->swap();
        } else { 

$sale_amount = '10.00';
$product = 'Drive-Plan';
include('partners/controller/record-sale.php);

            $this->user->subscription(Input::get('plan'))->create(Input::get('stripe_token'), ['email' => $this->user->email]);
        }

        return response(trans('app.upgradeSuccess'), 200);


    }


    /**
     * Swap current users plan to a new one.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function swapPlan() {
        if ($this->user->subscribed() && Input::get('plan')) {
            $this->user->subscription(Input::get('plan'))->swap();

            return response(trans('app.planSwapSuccess', ['plan' => Input::get('plan')]), 200);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attach new credit card to user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function addNewCard() {
        $this->user->updateCard(Input::get('stripe_token'));

        return response(trans('app.cardAddSuccess'), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Resume a canceled subscription.
     */
    public function resumeSubscription() {
        $this->user->subscription(Input::get('plan'))->resume(Input::get('token'));

        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Cancel users subscription.
     *
     * @return \App\User
     */
    public function unsubscribe() {
        $this->user->subscription()->cancel();

        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Return current users invoices.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInvoices() {
        return view('invoices')->with('invoices', $this->user->invoices())->with('settings', $this->settings);
    }

    /**
     * Download invoice with given id.
     *
     * @param {int|string} $id
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function downloadInvoice($id) {
        return $this->user->downloadInvoice($id, [
            'vendor'  => $this->settings->get('invoiceVendor'),
            'product' => $this->settings->get('invoiceProduct'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Return all created plans.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPlans() {
        $plans     = Plan::all();
        $formatted = [];

        foreach($plans->data as $plan) {
            $formatted[] = [
                'interval' => $plan['interval'],
                'name' => $plan['name'],
                'amount' => $plan['amount'] / 100,
                'currency' => $plan['currency'],
                'id' => $plan['id'],
                'created' => $plan['created'],
            ];
        }

        usort($formatted, function($a1, $a2) {
            if ($a1['created'] == $a2['created']) return 0;
            return ($a1['created'] < $a2['created']) ? -1 : 1;
        });

        return $formatted;
    }
}
```

Comment: include('partners/controller/record-sale.php'); add quote at end

Comment: Your init_set is outside the `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ending quote in this line:

```
include('partners/controller/record-sale.php);
```

**This should be:**

```
include('partners/controller/record-sale.php');
```

Comment: @ devpro. thanks again. new error is this: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /home/drive/public_html/application/app/Http/Controllers/PaymentsController.php on line 4

Comment: @cam r these inside the Php tag??? ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: deleted first few error reporting lines and now the page is loading :)

Comment: Thanks.so much. I will test if the script is functioning properly now.